# In Javascript, why is [1, 2] == [1, 2] or ({a : 1}) == ({a : 1}) false?

Tags: javascript

The following is done in Firebug:

```
>>> [1, 2] == [1, 2]
false

>>> ({a : 1}) == ({a : 1})
false
```

I thought Javscript has some rule that says, if an Object or Array has the same references to the same elements, then they are equal?

But even if I say

```
>>> foo = {a : 1}
Object { a=1}

>>> [foo] == [foo]
false

>>> ({a: foo}) == ({a: foo})
false
```

Is there a way to make it so that it can do the element comparison and return `true`?

Comment: object literals create new instances, defining two instances do not make them share the same reference.

Comment: it is not the "internal elements" that need to be equal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{ }` and `[ ]` are the same as `new Object` and `new Array`

And `new Object != new Object` (ditto with `Array`) because they are *new and different* objects.

If you want to know whether the content of two arbitary objects is the "same" for some value of same then a quick (but slow) fix is

`JSON.parse(o) === JSON.parse(o)`

A more elegant solution would be to define an equal function (untested)

```
var equal = function _equal(a, b) {
  // if `===` or `==` pass then short-circuit
  if (a === b || a == b) { 
    return true;
  }
  // get own properties and prototypes
  var protoA = Object.getPrototypeOf(a), 
      protoB = Object.getPrototypeOf(b),
      keysA = Object.keys(a), 
      keysB = Object.keys(b);

  // if protos not same or number of properties not same then false
  if (keysA.length !== keysB.length || protoA !== protoB) {
    return false;
  }
  // recurse equal check on all values for properties of objects
  return keysA.every(function (key) {
    return _equal(a[key], b[key]);
  });
};
```

[`equals` example](http://jsbin.com/ajajix/8/edit#source)

**Warning:** writing an equality function that "works" on all inputs is hard, some common gotchas are `(null == undefined) === true` and `(NaN === NaN) === false` neither of which I gaurd for in my function.

Nor have I dealt with any cross browser problems, I've just assumed ES5 exists.

Comment: You've got a lot to patch with that function. E.g. `equal({},{}) === false`. Also, I think you mean to recurse with `_equal`.

Comment: @davin `_equal` is just a convention and I dont know how to handle `{}` and `[]` elegantly. That also asks the question of whether `equal(Object.create(foo), Object.create(bar))` should be true or false.

Comment: @Raynos, convention, so what? if I decide to change that function to `myEqual` it will break because you need to change that twice.

Comment: @davin of course it will break. If you change it to `myEqual` you need to change all references to `equal` including any references inside `equal`

Comment: @Raynos, not if you recurse with the function's name property. That's what I'm trying to tell you. Change the recursion to reference `_equal` and you fix that problem!

Comment: @davin I think I patched the issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

To see what kind of code is necessary to do the deep equality you are talking about, check out [Underscore.js's `_.isEqual` function](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L632) or [QUnit's `deepEqual` implementation](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/qunit/qunit.js#L1028).

Comment: As the source of `_` and `QUnit` points out, deepEquality is a non trivial thing to do.

Comment: As you are quickly finding out in your answer ;)

Comment: I think my ES5 attempt is elegant and covers 99% of the use-cases!

Answer (score 0):

Its because javascript object literals do not share the same pointers. Instead a new pointer gets created for each one.  Consider the following example:

```
>>> ({a : 1}) == ({a : 1})
false
```

... but ...

```
>>> obj = ({a : 1});
Object

>>> obj == obj
true
```

`obj` is a pointer to the litteral object `{ a : 1 }`. So this works because the pointers are the same when you compare them

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing different objects.

```
>>> var a = [1,2] var b = [1,2]
>>> a == b
false
>>> a == a
true
```

If you want to test array equality you might want to use some library or just write the test yourself.