# IN javascript,why {}!==Object()?

Tags: javascript, object

Given

```
    var o = {};
    var p = new Object();

    p === o; //false

    o.__proto__===p.__proto__  // true
```

why is this false?

please tell me the immediate reason to return false??

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, why is \[1, 2\] == \[1, 2\] or ({a : 1}) == ({a : 1}) false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713794/in-javascript-why-is-1-2-1-2-or-a-1-a-1-false)

Comment: "Understanding pointers is not a skill, it's an aptitude". "p" and "o" are different pointers, both protos are the same one.

Comment: Even if `p` and `o` are different pointers, `===` can still be true. The important thing is whether the two pointers point to the same object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `===` for objects [is defined as](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6):

> 11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm
>
> The comparison `x === y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces `true` or
>   `false`. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 7. Return `true` if `x` and `y` refer to the same object. Otherwise, return
>   `false`.

In this case, although both are empty objects, they are created separately and hence do not refer to the same object.

As a side note, both constructions do the same thing; but it is common practice to use `{}`.

Comment: why `o.__proto__===p.__proto__` // true

Comment: @caizZZz: Because they both inherit from Object.prototype (there is only one of that).

Answer (score 6):

The two objects contain the same thing (i.e. nothing) but they are *not* the same object.

Javascript's object equality test requires that the two parameters refer to the *exact same object*.

Comment: what is the exact same object?

Comment: @caizZZz: Consider `var o = {}; var p = o;` `p` and `o` refer to the same object. If I modify a property of `p`, `o` is changed as well because they both point to the same instance.

Comment: but why `o.__proto__===p.__proto__` // true

Comment: Because the Object prototype isn't newly generated upon instantiation. `__proto__` still refers to Object's prototype in both cases.

Comment: @caizZZz: While it might be surprising that both of `__proto__` properties point to the same object, it should not be surprising that two *different* objects can refer to the same other object. Consider: `var foo = {}, bar = {x: foo, y: 42}, baz = {x: foo};`. Clearly `bar` and `baz` cannot be the same object but `bar.x === baz.x` is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript strict comparison for objects tests whether two expressions refer to the same objects (and so does the normal equals operator).

You create the first object using object literal `{}` which creates a new object with no properties.

You create the second object by calling `Object` constructor as a function. According to section 15.2.1.1 of [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) this also creates a new object just as if `new Object()` was used.

Thus you create two objects, store their references under `p` and `o` and check whether `p` and `o` refer to the same object. They don't.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you create an object, the result has its own, distinct identity. So even though they are both "empty", they are not the same thing. Hence the `===` comparison yields `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `===` , the result will show if items on both side is the "Same Instance"

If you like to comparing  two item are same type, you should use:

```
var o1 = {};
var o2 = new Object();

alert( typeof(o1) === typeof(o2));
```

and if you like to tell if the two object is considered equal (in properties and values), you should try [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isEqual) library and use the `isEqual` function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?

In that case, I will only give you some hints:
- Think about what the first two lines do. Do o and p refer to the same object after those two lines?
- Look up exactly what === does. Does it compare two objects to see if their structure are the same? Or does it compare the objects based on their identity?

Answer (score 0):

**Object** is an unordered collection of *properties* each of which contains a *primitive value, object*, or *function*. So, each object has properties and prototypes and there's no any sense to compare the one.