# Comparison Behaviour of JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, object, types

We suppose that we have 3 variables : a,b and c

```
var a = new Boolean(true);
var b = true;
var c = new Boolean(true);

console.log("First comparison : ", a == b);
// true
console.log("Second comparison : ", b == c);
// true
console.log("Contradiction : ", a == c);
// false
```

I already know that the keyword 'new' creates a new object. 
The type of this object, is simply object.

Mathematically, how can we explain this contradiction ?

Comment: Two distinct objects will never compare as equal.

Comment: a==c you are comparing two objects references instead of an object reference with a primitive data

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104913/behaviour-of-javascript-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first two examples, since the comparison involves a primitive value of `b`, `a` and `c` end up being coerced to primitives. In the last case, on the other hand, you are comparing two distinct objects, and therefore no coercion takes place.

To be precise, the double-equal comparison with a boolean uses this rule from the spec (taking the case of `b == c`):

> If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.

So this means that `ToNumber(b)` is compared with `c`. `ToNumber(b)` is 1. So we are comparing `1` with `c`. Next, the following rule is applied:

> If `Type(x)` is either `String` or `Number` and `Type(y)` is `Object`,
>   return the result of the comparison `x == ToPrimitive(y)`.

So this means we compare `1` with `ToPrimitive(c)` which is `ToPrimitive(Boolean(true))`. `ToPrimitive` invokes `valueOf`, which yields `1`. So we compare `1` to `1`. QED.

In the case of your third example, the following portion of the spec applies:

> If `Type(x)` is the same as `Type(y)`, then...Return true if `x` and `y` refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.

To answer your question:

> Mathematically, how can we explain this contradiction ?

It's not a matter of mathematics. It's a matter of the definition of comparisons in the JS spec.

Comment: If you want more information about coercion, check out https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md

Answer (score 0):

> Mathematically, how can we explain this contradiction?

If you think this is a contradiction is probably because you assumed that `==` defines an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

But it doesn't:

- It doesn't satisfy [reflexivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation), e.g. `NaN != NaN`.
- It doesn't satisfy [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), as you noticed.
- It satisfies [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation), though, but that alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this kind of behaviour can be explained from a mathematical standpoint.

What you are doing on the variables a and c is commonly referred as "boxing": taking a Javascript primitive value (undefined, null, String, Number, Boolean, Symbol in ES6) and calling it with the `new`operator.

The result of:

`var a = new Boolean(true);`

is a Javascript `Object`wrapping a `Boolean` primitive value.

The same invocation pattern implicitly happens when you use a primitive value as the context (`this`) in some of the language built-in facilities such as `Function.prototype.call` and `Function.prototype.apply`

Even replacing `==`with `===` would yield the same results, and that's because of how the Objects comparison work in JS.

Comment: I don't think you can box null and undefined. Also, replacing `==` with `===` would NOT yield the same results for the first two comparisons.

Comment: "taking a Javascript primitive value (undefined, null, String, Number, Boolean, Symbol in ES6) and calling it with the newoperator" --- that's not correct. `Boolean` is not a primitive value, it's a constructor.