# Compare equal objects gives false, javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [
  {
     groups: {
       TypeID: 'AV601'
     }
  }
]

var prop = {
  TypeID: 'AV601'
}

console.log(arr[0].groups);
console.log(prop);
console.log(arr[0].groups === prop)// false
```

How can this give false? They are the same?

https://jsbin.com/giholunupa/edit?js,console

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are two identical objects not equal to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other).

Answer (score 1):

It's because Javascript compares objects by reference, not by keys equality. Those two objects simply have the same key name with the equal key value, but in memory, they point to different address.

```
let o1= {}; // points to address "#aaa" in memory
let o2= {}; // points to address "#bbb" in memory

o1 === o2; // false
```

Comment: Ok. So I have to compare each prop?

Comment: It is better to refer to the Q&A of which this is a duplicate

Comment: @PerStröm, it depends on what is your task. If you want to know whether objects have the same key/value pairs, yes, you have to compare by keys. If you want to know if its the same object, you have to compare by reference.