# Why {} !== {} in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was going through Map Documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). In Examples, under Using Map Object, Object Literal - `{}` is used as key to store value. But, the value in Map can't be retrieved using Object Literal.

I verified this in Browser Console and found that Object Literal is not equal to itself. Also, the Function Expression - `function() {}` is not equal to itself.

I couldn't find the reason behind this. If required, I can ask a different question for Function Expression.

Comment: Because the two objects aren't the same reference/don't refer to the same object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. I was reading Object Documentation on MDN. But was not sure whether it creates a new object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you do {}, it creates a new empty object, so when you do {} == {}, you're comparing two different objects. This comparison is done by reference, so it returns false.