# simlibehaviour of `property` of Chai: expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.have.property('x', {a: 1})

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, chai

I have the following Chai + Mocha code, of which the results are very confusing me:

```
describe('Have Object Property', () => {
  it('should have the object property', () => {
    expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.have.property('x', {a: 1})
  })
  it('should have the property of an object property', () => {
    expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.have.property('x.a', 1)
  })
  it('should deeply have the object property', () => {
    expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.have.deep.property('x', {a: 1})
  })
  it('should deeply have the property of an object property', () => {
    expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.have.deep.property('x.a', 1)
  })
})
```

The results are:

```
Have Object Property
  1) should have the object property
  2) should have the property of an object property
  3) should deeply have the object property
  ✓ should deeply have the property of an object property


2 passing (53ms)
3 failing

  1) Have Object Property should have the object property:
     AssertionError: expected { x: { a: 1 } } to have a property 'x' of { a: 1 }, but got { a: 1 }
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:7:33)

  2) Have Object Property should have the property of an object property:
     AssertionError: expected { x: { a: 1 } } to have a property 'x.a'
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:10:33)

  3) Have Object Property should deeply have the object property:
     AssertionError: expected { x: { a: 1 } } to have a deep property 'x' of { a: 1 }, but got { a: 1 }
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:13:38)
```

In the four cases:

1. why I cannot directly put `{a: 1}` as the value of property `x`?
2. the object has no obj["x.a"] property
3. using deep with only a single property (no dot) is the same as not using deep
4. only this is working, but this is really not as convenient and directly as the first case.

### Update and Comments on the duplicate mark:

What I am expecting, according to [Chai's `deep` doc](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep), is that, **case 3 should pass**, which is not.

I knew there is a similar question here: [Why are two identical objects not equal to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other). But it is not my question.  I am aware that two *identical (they are not identical actually)*  objects are not *equal*, in terms of `==` or `===`.

My question is more about:

- it is making more sense that: during test, what we are expecting is whether two objects are value equal not whether they are referring to the same one (reference equal)?

Comment: 2) The object has no `obj["x.a"]` property 4) Using `deep` with only a single property (no dot) is the same as not using `deep`

Comment: Oops, looks like I confused `deep` with `nested` in my first comment. I'm a bit confused though because [the Chai docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep) say that `expect({x: {a: 1}}).to.have.deep.property('x', {a: 1})` does indeed work. You have to use `deep` to avoid reference comparison.

Comment: You're using ["Identical"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)) exactly the wrong way round - it means same-reference-equal, not same-shape/value-equal.

Comment: yes, this is my question, the Chai doc say `deep` should work in this way

Comment: I edited my question