# Object Equality and Value Equality in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not able to understand how does javascript handles object equality.
Please can anybody explain me the below output?

`1. var x = 3;
 2. var y = 3;
 3. var obj1 = {};
 4. var obj2 = {};
 5. var obj3 = obj1;
 6. x == y
 7. x === y
 8. obj1 == obj2
 9. obj1 === obj2
10. obj1 == obj3
11. obj1 === obj3`

Output:

> 6. true
> 7. true
> 8. false
> 9. false
> 10. true
> 11. true

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11704971/5267751).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are two identical objects not equal to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other)

Answer (score 1):

When you compare objects using either `==` or `===`, the comparison is only true if the objects are *the same object*, not merely identically-constructed objects, but the very same object.

If you want to compare objects for whether they are identically constructed, you might want to look into something like LoDash: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5

Particular relevant here is the `_.isEqual()` function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#isEqual

Comment: But if i try to check `[] == []` , it also returns **false**. Are arrays = object in javascript?

Comment: You can think of arrays as a special class of objects, yes, and that's certainly true for how they're compared. LoDash's `_.isEqual()` function will handle such array comparisons as well.