# Two strings in JavaScript of the same type and value do not evaluate to true when matched against associative array

Tags: javascript, associative-array

```
monthDateMapper(month) {
  const months = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03'
                ,'Apr': '04', 'May': '05', 'Jun': '06'
                ,'July': '07', 'Aug': '08', 'Sep': '09'
                , 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec':'12'}
  let monthDate;
  for(var monthAbrev in months) {
    month === monthAbrev ? monthDate = months[monthAbrev] : monthDate = 'Invalid Value'
  }
  return monthDate
}
```

Presuming I hit my function with monthDateMapper('Apr'), why does my conditional never assign monthDate to be 04.

I've read a few articles on the subject of matching strings in Javascript; most of them say that this kind of type checking is never going to be true, even if both types are strings and the same value:

- [Why are two identical objects not equal to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

One of the answers suggested to use lodash _.isEqual(), this did not work. Also I tried converting lower-case on both sides, also trying to convert them both further to 2 strings. I confirmed they were both two strings through typeOf.

Is there a way around it?

Comment: You can simply do `return months[month] || 'Invalid Value';` instead of that loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over all the keys and you are not stopping the iteration when your condition is true. BTW you do not need to iterate over the months :)

```
function monthDateMapper(month) {
   const months = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03'
            ,'Apr': '04', 'May': '05', 'Jun': '06'
            ,'July': '07', 'Aug': '08', 'Sep': '09'
            , 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec':'12'}

  return months[month] || 'Invalid Value'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you loop 12 times. One of those times, `monthDate` is assigned the value `04`, but the other 11 times it is assigned the value `Invalid Value`. Unless the correct value is assigned on the last iteration of the loop, it is simply overwritten with `Invalid Value`.

As Andy noted, your code can be reduced to:

```
monthDateMapper(month) {
  const months = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03'
                ,'Apr': '04', 'May': '05', 'Jun': '06'
                ,'July': '07', 'Aug': '08', 'Sep': '09'
                , 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec':'12'}
  return months[month] ? months[month] : 'Invalid Value';
}
```

Comment: `return months[month] || 'Invalid Value'` is more succinct :)

Answer (score 1):

You compare 12 times and you assign 12 times, so the last compare is for `Dec` which assigns 'Invalid value'. This is caused by flawed logic on multiple levels.

I think you'd better use an array of month names and `indexOf()`:

```js
function monthDateMapper(month) {
  const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  var index = months.indexOf(month);
  return index == -1 ? 'Invalid Value' : index + 1; // or (index+1).toString() if needed
};

console.log(monthDateMapper('Jan'));
console.log(monthDateMapper('Apr'));
console.log(monthDateMapper('Dec'));
console.log(monthDateMapper('ZZZ'));
```

PS Note that I also changed 'July' to 'Jul' for consistency.