# How to remove duplicate Date from array of Date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, set

I m Trying to remove the duplicate date from an array of Date like

```
let dates = ["date1","date2","date1","date3"];
```

I convert dates into Set but it's doesn't remove duplicate, but when I try it with other datatypes instead of Date in work, Where is the problem?

`let uniq = dates => [...new Set(dates)`];

Comment: Your `date1` and the others are simple dates like `2018-06-07 11:42` ?

Comment: If the dates are Objects, then they'll never `===` each other if they were created separately. If you want to deduplicate like that, you could convert the dates to timestamps first

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other

Comment: @SurenSrapyan not date object contain date with 0  hour, minute, sec and milisecond

Answer (score 3):

Because your dates are objects they will we compared via references. Two objects can't be equal though they have all equal properties.

`const a = { name: 'Test' }` and `const b = { name = 'Test' }` have identical values but their references (*address in the memory*) are not equal. So why Set does not work in your case.

You can work with their *string representations*. Strings are going to be compared via their *value*. `const a = 'Test'` and `const b = 'Test'` are identical in this case. Map them using `toString` function and then insert them into the Set. Same dates will have the same string representations and so they will not be unique.

```js
const dates = [
    new Date(), // Will be the same as the below 3 dates at runtime
    new Date(), 
    new Date(), 
    new Date(), 
    new Date(2015, 1, 1)
];

const uniqueDates = [...new Set(dates.map(date => date.toString()))];

console.log(uniqueDates);
```

Comment: "The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references." 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: With objects it will compare references

Comment: Cleverness is all well and good, but likely the OP has no idea why the above does what it does, nor why the Dates are now Strings.

Comment: @RobG Adding some explanation

Comment: @SurenSrapyan i just posted the reference for the OP :)

Comment: @Sid Ok. I think you write it to me )

Comment: @SurenSrapyan it returns date like Tue Jun 05 2018 05:45:00 GMT+0545 (+0545) I want date object within array, but it helps me for finding solution I m working in that

Comment: @SurenSrapyanya exactly i do the same and i m testing it now

Comment: Rather than parsing strings, consider using time values to avoid all parsing: `[...new Set(dates.map(date => +date))].map(tv => new Date(tv))`. Also worth noting that the resulting array will be new Dates, not references to the original Dates (which may be an issue).