# How do I stop useEffect from making my component re-render infinitely?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Edited again to explain that `===` compares the memory location of objects ([Why are two identical objects not equal to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other)) which is why the `useEffect()` kept running again and again and again... I think I have it sorted now but will leave the post here without an answer for a while in case I'm talking absolute gibberish and someone would like to correct me :)

--- End of second edit ----

I have edited my `Routes` const to log the different `sessions` to the console. As you can see, they are equal but for some reason, the computer doesn't seem to think so. Does anyone have any idea why???

```
edited Routes (to show the values)
const Routes = () => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState(getSessionCookie());
  console.log('Route session before: ', session);


  useEffect(
    () => {
      //setSession(getSessionCookie());
      const stateCookie = session;
      const getCookie = getSessionCookie();
      console.log('stateCookie: ', stateCookie);
      console.log('getCookie: ', getCookie);
      console.log('Are equal? ', stateCookie === getCookie);
    },
    [session]
  );
  console.log('Route session after: ', session);
```

[image: Console log]

----- End of edit -------

I found a [tutorial](https://www.jmfurlott.com/handling-user-session-react-context/) online to assist me in managing user sessions but I keep having a problem with the re-rendering of the component unless I take out the useEffect dependency. I've logged the values and types of the `session` variable but it doesn't change so I don't understand why the re-render keeps happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { SessionContext, getSessionCookie, setSessionCookie } from "./session";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const LoginHandler = ({ history }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    // NOTE request to api login here instead of this fake promise
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r(), 1000));
    setSessionCookie({ email });
    history.push("/");
    setLoading(false);
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <h4>Logging in...</h4>;
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter email address"
          value={email}
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const ProtectedHandler = ({ history }) => {
  const session = useContext(SessionContext);
  if (session.email === undefined) {
    history.push("/login");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h6>Protected data for {session.email}</h6>
      <Link to="/logout">Logout here</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

const LogoutHandler = ({ history }) => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      Cookies.remove("session");
      history.push("/login");
    },
    [history]
  );

  return <div>Logging out!</div>;
};

const Routes = () => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState(getSessionCookie());
  console.log('Routes session before: ', session);
  console.log('Routes session before typeof: ', typeof session);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      setSession(getSessionCookie());
    },
    [session] // <-------------- this is the dependency that seems to be causing the trouble
  );
  console.log('Routes session: ', session);
  console.log('Routes session typeof: ', typeof session);

  return (
    <SessionContext.Provider value={session}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <h6 style={{ display: "inline" }}>Nav Bar</h6>
          <h6 style={{ display: "inline", marginLeft: "5rem" }}>
            {session.email || "No user is logged in"}
          </h6>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginHandler} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={LogoutHandler} />
          <Route path="*" component={ProtectedHandler} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </SessionContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Routes />
  </div>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

session.js

```
import React from "react";
import * as Cookies from "js-cookie";

export const setSessionCookie = (session) => {
  Cookies.remove("session");
  Cookies.set("session", session, { expires: 14 });
};

export const getSessionCookie = () => {
  const sessionCookie = Cookies.get("session");

  if (sessionCookie === undefined) {
    console.log('undefined');
    return {};
  } else {
    return return JSON.parse(sessionCookie);
  }
};

export const SessionContext = React.createContext(getSessionCookie());
```

Comment: are you sure it's that what one that is causing it ?

Comment: No, not really. All I know is if I remove `session` and just have `[]`, the thing doesn't render off into the sunset.

Comment: haha. im guessing session is an object, how do you know it hasn't changed? maybe there is a timestamp inside that is changing?

Comment: Yes, it is an object. I haven't been able to log in yet so the object is still just `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a very common issue when working with `useEffect`, you should not have an object inside the dependency array, because Object just refers its reference, not actual value. And when session is created, it will have a new reference even when your prefer property value is the same => This is why it creates infinite loop.

If you put `session` as a dependency, you should have explicitly compare the property value, like `session.value`.

I'm not using context API much, but I guess there might be something wrong in your `<Routes />` component, there might not need to update the session inside `<Routes />` since it just plays as a provider role. Usually, this is the place you assign an initial context value.

Once user's logged in successfully, you can update session inside `<LoginHandler />`. The other child components which consume the context value just need to use `useContext` to get the latest session value.

So, basically your app might look like this:

```
// sessionContext.js
const SessionContext = React.createContext({
  session: {},
  setSession: () => {},
});

// components/routes.js
const Routes = () => {
  const [session, setSession] = useState({})
  const contextSession = {
    session,
    setSession
  }

  return (
    <SessionContext.Provider value={contextSession}>
      {children}
    </SessionContext.Provider>
  )
}

// components/childComponent.js
const ChildComponent = () => {
  const { session } = useContext(SessionContext)

  if (!session)
    return null;
  
  return <div>Logged-in</div>
}
```

For complicated state management, I suggest having a look at redux, you won't need to use context like the above example.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Duc Hong. I will try your suggestions to see if I can get it to work. If so, I will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: the main thing here is understanding context API and its usage, your logic relies on `<Routes />` while keep updating it in `useEffect`, actually child components doesn't need to receive its session value via props, it can directly get this data via `useContext`

Comment: Thanks - clearly I need to research `useContext` and the rest of the `Hook` functionality to understand what to do!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you should only be logging the sessions when the session is updated/changed, you should do a comparison before updating the state, otherwise, it will cause an infinite loop as you are constantly updating the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // assuming that session is not an array or object
  if (getSessionCookie().email === session.email) {
    return;
  }
  setSession(getSessionCookie());
}, [session]);
```

Likewise, on your `LogoutHandler` component, you shouldn't update the `history` object while having it as part of the dependency array. In fact, there is no need to call `history.push()`, as you should already be in that route when the component is rendered. You should only remove the cookies once, thus you can call that when the component is mounted.

```
const LogoutHandler = ({ history }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    Cookies.remove("session");
  }, []);

  return <div>Logging out!</div>;
};
```

Comment: I'm going to try your suggestions now. What confuses me is the sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/389o3qyoq5?file=/src/index.tsx) works as is...

Comment: I was just about to tell you that it's an object :)

It's an empty object currently as I haven't been able to use the code to log in yet.

Comment: Yeah.. In that case you will need to do a comparison between the properties. Is `email ` the only field in the session object? I have updated my answer

Comment: It worked for the login portion but the logout then gets an `Maximum update depth exceeded` error

Comment: Did you try what I have implemented on LogoutHandler? I used an empty array (`[]`) for the dependency array of the useEffect hook

Comment: Yes, I did. When I used the logout code I had before, it didn't crash but it also didn't take me to the login page.

Comment: @DRobinson hmm.. that is another issue. Are you still stuck on it?

Comment: Yes, still stuck. I've edited my original post to show the Matrix has gone mad.