# Quick question about leetcode 101.Symmetric Tree

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why the first dfs returns false and the second returns true. From my understanding || operator returns true if one of the expressions is true. thanks, guys!

```js
var isSymmetric = function(root) {
    if (!root) return true;

    return dfs(root.left, root.right);
};

const dfs = (left, right) => {
    if (left.left || right.right) {
        return left.left === right.right;
    }
    if (left.val !== right.val) return false;

    return dfs(left.left, right.right) && dfs(left.right, right.left)
}

const dfs = (left, right) => {
    if (!left.left || !right.right) {
        return left.left === right.right;
    }
    if (left.val !== right.val) return false;

    return dfs(left.left, right.right) && dfs(left.right, right.left)
}
```

Comment: With the first one you immediately get into the `if` for the root node. And since the left and right nodes are *different*, it returns false. With the second, you only get into the `if` for *leaf nodes* and then it returns `true` because `left.left` and `right.right` are the same value that signals "missing" - either `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for helping me! I think I need a clarification why the first one immediately goes into `if`? if statement is checking if left.left or right.right exist? And I'm not too sure with the second (you mean second dfs logic?)

Comment: In the first case you check if either `left` or `right` exists. For the root node (assuming the tree more nodes) that is going to be true. However, those would be two *different objects*, so they will never be equal. The second `dfs` logic only goes in the `if` if *neither* `left.left` *nor* `right.right` exist. So, if both are missing. This will *only* happen if `left` and `right` are leaf nodes - it will never trigger for the root node (again, assuming there are more nodes).

Comment: @VLAZ isn't first case is checking if `root.left.left` and `root.left.right` node exist? I'm confuse by check if either `left` or `right`. And if its two different object it should never be equal but second dfs logic pass all the test cases.

Comment: *If* `root.left.left` and `root.right.right` exist then you compare `root.left.left === root.right.right` [which will never be true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other). However if *both* `node.left.left` and `node.right.right` are `null` (or `undefined` - whatever marks "nothing" in your case) then `null === null` (or `undefined === undefined`) is `true`.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry I miss wrote `root.left.left` and `root.right.right` I wanted to check `root.left` and `root.right` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample tree with the nodes labelled for ease.

```
     A
   /   \
  B     C
 / \   / \
D   E F   G
```

Using this code:

```
const dfs = (left, right) => {
    if (left.left || right.right) {
        return left.left === right.right;
    }
    if (left.val !== right.val) return false;

    return dfs(left.left, right.right) && dfs(left.right, right.left)
}
```

Starting from the root **A**, `left` would be **B** and `right` would be **C**.

The first `if` would check whether `left.left` (which is **D**) and `right.right` (which is **G**) exist. Since they do, it tries to directly compare the nodes.

[Two different objects are never equal to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other)

```js
const D = {val: "X"};
const G = {val: "X"};

console.log(D === G);
```

Which means that the `if` will immediately return `false` for any tree.

Using this condition instead radically changes the semantics:

```
if (!left.left || !right.right) {
    return left.left === right.right;
}
```

Now the code checks whether both `left.left` and `right.right` are missing. Given the tree above, this is *not true* for the root node **A**, since both **D** and **G** are there. The condition would only trigger for a tree of this shape:

```
  X
 / \
Y   Z
```

Starting with **X**, `left` would be **Y** and `right` would be **Z**.

In this case `left.left` and `right.right` are both the same value - most likely either `null` or `undefined` (depending on how the tree was built up).

```js
console.log(null === null);
console.log(undefined === undefined);
```

Therefore, in the second case it works but by accident only because missing nodes are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        def dfs(root: Optional[TreeNode]): 
            if not root:
               yield None  # extra value for each encountered None
               return
            yield root.val  # pre-order instead of in-order
            yield from dfs(root.left)
            yield from dfs(root.right)
                
        def invert(root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> None:
            if not root:
               return        
             invert(root.left)
             invert(root.right)
             root.left, root.right = root.right, root.left
        
        org_root_list = list(dfs(root))
        invert(root)
        return list(dfs(root)) == org_root_list
```

Try this code using Python 3 format at Leetcode you will pass...