# Learning JavaScript. My palindrome Number solution is not working for multiples of 10

Tags: javascript, palindrome

This code is working fine except any number which is multiples of 10s. I tested with 121, -121, 55, -55. It was executing fine. but with 10 it's not generating the right answer.

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {

var convertToString= toString(x);
var splitString= convertToString.split("");
var reversedString= splitString.reverse();
 
if(x<0){
        return false;
    }
    
    if(reversedString == splitString){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with this code, although you're on the right track. First, your usage of `toString` is slightly wrong:

```
toString(101); // '[object Undefined]'
```

`toString` should be called as a method of `x`, like `x.toString()`. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) for more details. If you change it to `x.toString()`, it works:

```
var x = 101; // "101"
```

Second, you are currently comparing arrays with `==`, which won't do what you want. Notice that:

```
[0, 1] == [0, 1] // false
```

whereas

```
"01" == "01" // true
```

This is because JS compares strings by value, but doesn't compare objects (which includes arrays) by value. For example:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 1;
console.log(x == y); // true

var a = [1];
var b = [1];
console.log(a == b); // false
console.log(a == a); // true
```

To learn more about this, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other#:%7E:text=As%20from%20The%20Definitive%20Guide,values%20in%20the%20same%20order.) or try googling for 'javascript pass by reference'. But in brief, one solution to your problem would be to just use strings, which work as you would expect with `==`.

After fixing these problems, your code should look like this:

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {

    var convertToString= String(x);
    var reversedString= convertToString.split("").reverse().join("");
 
    if(x<0){
        return false;
    }
    
    if(convertToString == reversedString){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

You could also consider shortening the if statement at the end and making the spacing more consistent:

```
var isPalindrome = function(x) {

    var convertToString = String(x);
    var reversedString = convertToString.split("").reverse().join("");
 
    if(x < 0){
        return false;
    }
    
    return convertToString == reversedString;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of your function is totally wrong. It shouldn't work with any given input.

```
if(convertToString == splitString) // comparison
```

here you are using comparison operator to compare both values, but underneath the hood the compiler is comparing [ ] = [ ] the values inside the arrays doesn't matter it will always be true.
you have to find a way to compare the values inside both of the arrays to get the function to work. (Spoiler : you could use some kind of loop to compare the values)

And use the toString function like this,

```
var convertToString= x.toString();
```

to get stringified value of x.