# The user is following himself

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, mongoose, logic

I wrote a function for following & unfollowing users and in the first line of code I made if statement to make it so the user can't follow himself but the user can follow himself even though that

the followUser code:

```
const followUnfollowUser = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const userToModify = await User.findById(id);
        const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user._id);

        if(userToModify === currentUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "You cannot follow/unfollow yourself!" });
        }

        if(!userToModify || !currentUser) return res.status(400).json({ message: "User not found!" });

        const isFollowing = currentUser.following.includes(id);

        if (isFollowing) {
            // unfollow user
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $pull: { followers: req.user._id } });
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $pull: { following: id } });
            res.status(200).json({ message: "User unfollowed successfully" });
        } else {
            // Follow User
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { followers: req.user._id } });
            await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $push: { following: id } });
            res.status(200).json({ message: "User followed successfully" });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
        console.log("Error in follow or unfollow User: ", err.message);
    }
};
```

Note: I'm using post method in router file. Is this fine or I should use (patch or put) for that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking why a user may be able to follow themselves?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are two identical objects not equal to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other)

Comment: @Kaddath  I've solved it look to my answer down below

Answer (score 3):

Two objects will not be the same:

```
if(userToModify === currentUser) {
```

Even if they intuitively represent the same information, they are different object instances.

But look at how you *get* those objects:

```
const userToModify = await User.findById(id);
const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user._id);
```

If those *identifiers* are the same then you're fetching two instances of the same record, right?  Then just compare the identifiers:

```
const { id } = req.params;

if(id === req.user._id) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "You cannot follow/unfollow yourself!" });
}

const userToModify = await User.findById(id);
const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user._id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by adding `toString()` method after the id like this:

`if(id === req.user._id.toString())` etc.