# Search in json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am new to json. My json array

```
[{"seat_number":"834"},{"seat_number":"8F3"},{"seat_number":"891"},
{"seat_number":"814"},{"seat_number":"4081"},{"seat_number":"8F1"},
{"seat_number":"8F9"},{"seat_number":"4039"},{"seat_number":"0"},
{"seat_number":"509"},{"seat_number":"662"},{"seat_number":"561"},
{"seat_number":"791"},{"seat_number":"849"}]
```

I want to find seat number already exist in array.

```
if(($scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.indexOf($scope.employeeData.new_seat_number))>-1)
{
alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your `indexOf` is looking for `834` when it needs to look for `{seat_number: 834}` (the latter is not so easy given how equality checks don't work).

Comment: which framework are you using ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the hard way if you want

```
var data = [
  {"seat_number":"834"},{"seat_number":"8F3"},
  {"seat_number":"891"},{"seat_number":"814"},
  {"seat_number":"4081"},{"seat_number":"8F1"},
  {"seat_number":"8F9"},{"seat_number":"4039"},
  {"seat_number":"0"},{"seat_number":"509"},
  {"seat_number":"662"},{"seat_number":"561"},
  {"seat_number":"791"},{"seat_number":"849"}
];

function matchingSeat(x) {
  return data.some(function(elem) {
    return elem.seat_number === x;
  });
}

console.log("831", matchingSeat("834")); // 834 true
console.log("8F3", matchingSeat("8F3")); // 8F3 true
console.log("999", matchingSeat("999")); // 999 false
```

I think that's a total pain tho. Once you have some reusable utility functions at your disposal, this problem becomes a lot easier to solve.

> **Don't freak out**: the ES5 solution is below

```
// ES6
// reusable lib
let prop = y => x => x[y];

let comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));

let eq = y => x => x === y;

let some = f => xs => xs.some(f);
```

Now write some helpers to solve your task

```
let eqSeat = x => comp(eq(x))(prop("seat_number"));
let hasSeat = comp(some)(eqSeat);
```

Check it out

```
console.log("831", hasSeat("834")(data)); // 831 true
console.log("8F3", hasSeat("8F3")(data)); // 8F3 true
console.log("999", hasSeat("999")(data)); // 999 false
```

---

Here's the same code in **ES5**

```
// ES5
// reusable lib
var prop = function prop(y) {
  return function (x) {
    return x[y];
  };
};

var comp = function comp(f) {
  return function (g) {
    return function (x) {
      return f(g(x));
    };
  };
};

var eq = function eq(y) {
  return function (x) {
    return x === y;
  };
};

var some = function some(f) {
  return function (xs) {
    return xs.some(f);
  };
};
```

Your helpers

```
var eqSeat = function eqSeat(x) {
  return comp(eq(x))(prop("seat_number"));
};

var hasSeat = comp(some)(eqSeat);
```

Try it out

```
console.log("831", hasSeat("834")(data)); // 831 true
console.log("8F3", hasSeat("8F3")(data)); // 8F3 true
console.log("999", hasSeat("999")(data)); // 999 false
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `({a:10}) !== ({a:10})`, therefore your `indexOf` won't work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713794/) related question.

Knowing that, there are several ways to do this (assuming `typeof $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number === 'string'`):

1) Use a `for`-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.employeeSeat.seat_array[i].seat_number === $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number) {
        alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
    }
}
```

2) Use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
if ($scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.some(function(seat) { return seat.seat_number === $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number; })) {
    alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
}
```

*Note: `.some` is the best answer other than the good old `for`-loop in my opinion. The rest are explorations of the `Array` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).*

3) Use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
if ($scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.findIndex(function(seat) { return seat.seat_number === $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number; }) !== -1) {
    alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
}
```

4) Use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
if ($scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.find(function(seat) { return seat.seat_number === $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number; })) {
    alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
}
```

*Note: `.find` and `.findIndex` are **experimental** technologies. Check their [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) [tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Browser_compatibility) to see if `.find` is available for your browser. If not, use their [poly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) [fills](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).*

5) Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
if ($scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.map(function(seat) { return seat.seat_number; }).indexOf($scope.employeeData.new_seat_number)) !== -1) {
    alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
}
```

*Note: Using `.map` will be much **slower** as `.map` iterates through the array running a function that will be used to create a brand new array.*

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++)
{
  if(myjson[i].seat_number == expectednumber)
  {
    alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the item in your array is a object, so you can not use indexOf to find the seat_number.

you can try:

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.length; ++i){
    if($scope.employeeData.new_seat_number == $scope.employeeSeat.seat_array[i].seat_number){
        alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make use of `filter()`. If `arr` is empty, then it should show the `alert`.

```
var arr=$scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.filter(function(item){
  return $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number == item.seat_number;
})
if(!arr.length){
 alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
}
```

You can also make use of `some()`.

```
var bool=$scope.employeeSeat.seat_array.some(function(item){
  return $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number == item.seat_number;
})
if(bool){
 alert('Seat number is already assigned.Please Check');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array find prototype. You may find detail on this method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Example:

```
var items = [{"seat_number":"834"},{"seat_number":"8F3"},{"seat_number":"891"},{"seat_number":"814"},{"seat_number":"4081"},{"seat_number":"8F1"},{"seat_number":"8F9"},{"seat_number":"4039"},{"seat_number":"0"},{"seat_number":"509"},{"seat_number":"662"},{"seat_number":"561"},{"seat_number":"791"},{"seat_number":"849"}];

var newSeatNumber = $scope.employeeData.new_seat_number;
var result = items.find(function(item) {return item.seat_number == newSeatNumber ;})


console.log(result); // Object { seat_number="791"} if found, else undefined
if(result)
{
    //Do your stuff. Item exits in array
}
```

Comment: Note: This is an __experimental__ technology, part of the ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) proposal. Check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) to see if `.find` will work on your browser.

Comment: @usandfriends, I agree. You can use Polyfill but only if you are using this type of comparison very often. Vote up for you.

Comment: yup. Here is the link to the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill).

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need such a JSON Structure ?

```
I've changed the structure a little.
{
  "seat_numbers" :["894", "900", "814", "591", "789", ..]
}
```

Load your JSON using javascript/jquery

```
var yourSearchingSeat = "900";
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    var seat_numbers = data.seat_numbers
    for (i=0; i<seat_numbers.length;i++) {
        if (seat_numbers[i] == yourSearchingSeat) {
            console.log("Seat number"+yourSearchingSeat+" already exists");
        }
    }
});
```