# Check if json array is empty at store vuex

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to show a button if my array of object has some data, so basilcy in my store(vuex) i defined a array like this:

```
state: {
    document: []
},
```

i append data to this array from other components and i already checked that the data is appending right, no problem here.

So i want to show the button just if there is some data:

```
<div class="row margin-above">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" v-for="section in this.$store.getters.getDocument">
        <div class="panel-body quote" >
            <p>{{section.key}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="this.$store.getters.getDocument != '[]'">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create Document</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

there is the button, i want to hide the whole div with the button if the condition matches, but it is not working the button is always there, any help?

Comment: why you use single quotations in `this.$store.getters.getDocument != '[]'`? Isn't `document` an array?

Comment: i tried without it either, same result

Comment: what if you do `v-if="document.length > 0"` ?

Comment: @FilipeCosta Yeah, if your `document` is an array, you shouldn't use "!=", see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313263/why-is-in-javascript

Comment: makes sense, im sleeping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check its length property.

```
<div v-if="this.$store.getters.getDocument.length != 0">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create Document</button>
</div>
```

Or assign the vuex variable to `null` when there are no elements. Than this should work.

```
<div v-if="this.$store.getters.getDocument">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create Document</button>
</div>
```

Comment: worked, dunno i had tried something like that, thank you friend :D

Answer (score 1):

In your store did u define the getter  "getDocument", if so add a computed property in your component, it much cleaner and more reusable then referencing the store getters in the template directly:

```
computed : {
   document: function() { 
       return this.$store.getters.getDocument; 
   }
}
```

in the template:

```
<div v-if="document.length">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Create Document</button>
</div>
```